# Insert characters within a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

During exporting from Adobe Illustrator(AI) file to SVG I am getting style of font-size without any unit. So I need to update the font-size portion with unit.

How can I replace subject using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) ?

```
font-size:6.3875;
```

to

```
font-size:6.3875px;
```

Comment: Why use a regex? `substr('font-size:6.3875;', 0, -1).'px;'` or `rtrim($string, ';').'px;'` or `str_replace($string, ';', 'px;')`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn `OP` will `SVG` content and he want replace `font-size:??` to `font-size:??px` ?? = any numeric value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$input = preg_replace('/(font-size\s*:\s*[^;]+);/i', '$1px;', $input);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hY2dQ1/1)

Comment: How you be so genius!

Comment: Yes bookmark that site s that is very useful regex demo site.

Answer (score 1):

```
 (.*?);
```

Replace with

```
 \1px;
```

This should work.

Comment: It's better to use `$1` than `\1` in replacement part. `\1` is for backreference in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to capture anything,

```
<?php
$mystring = 'font-size:6.3875;';
$re = "px";
echo preg_replace("~(?=;$)~", $re, $mystring);
?>
```

Output:

```
font-size:6.3875px;
```